# How do I find the depth of visited nodes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

Say I have an object like this:

```
{
  visited: true,
  value: 1,
  children: [
    {
      visited: true,
      value: 2,
      children: [
        {
          visited: true,
          value: 5,
          children: []
        },
        {
          visited: false,
          value: 6,
          children: []
        },
        {
          visited: false,
          value: 7,
          children: []
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      visited: false,
      value: 3,
      children: []
    },
    {
      visited: false,
      value: 4,
      children: []
    },
  ]
}
```

Is there a easy way traverse this without using any JS frameworks to finally return 3 ?

I have written a recursive function to check for objects with {visited: true} in each level and then drill down further until I hit a visited node with no children. I was just wondering if there is any optimization I could apply to this??

Comment: you'd use a for loop, or a while loop, why would you have to use a JS framework for this? you might be able to optimize with tail call recursion. You have many questions in this piece, so you should focus on one.

Comment: So there actually is no issue? If not you should post your algorithm to code review. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @theblindprophet [codereview.se] isn't *algorithm review*, it's *code review*. We review the real actual implementation, not some hypothetical pseudo-code. Please see [a guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788)

Comment: Recursive functions usually perform well on modern JS engines. Show us your code and we can point out further optimization possibilities (if any),

Comment: "Finally return 3"? How will the algo know to do this? What's the condition? objects for `3` and `4` are identical apart from the `value`. So again, why is only `3` special for you?

Comment: @Mat'sMug. I am assuming he already has an algorithm in code, thats what it sounded like to me. I mentioned nothing of pseudo code.

Comment: The recursive approach is just fine. You can create a `while` loop to possibly optimize the memory usage but I don’t think it will affect the execution of your code too much.

Comment: @theblindprophet "you should post your *algorithm* to code review" should have been "you should post your **working code** to code review" then.

Comment: My apologies sir...

Comment: A recursive approach sounds good to me.

Comment: While building the object you can keep this information in each parent object or in a variable... So write will be expensive but finding depth will be O(1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative function. It assumes that visited nodes are all in parent-child relationship, forming one unique path in the tree. As a bonus it returns the values of the visited nodes. The number of visited nodes is then of course the length of that array:

```js
function collectVisited(child) {
    var data, values = [];
    while ((data = child).visited) {
        child = {};
        values.push(data.value);
        for (child of data.children) {
            if (child.visited) break;
        }
    }
    return values;
}

// Sample data
var data = {
  visited: true,
  value: 1,
  children: [
    {
      visited: true,
      value: 2,
      children: [
        {
          visited: true,
          value: 5,
          children: []
        },
        {
          visited: false,
          value: 6,
          children: []
        },
        {
          visited: false,
          value: 7,
          children: []
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      visited: false,
      value: 3,
      children: []
    },
    {
      visited: false,
      value: 4,
      children: []
    },
  ]
};

var values = collectVisited(data);

console.log(values.length);
console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not claiming this is the best/fastest/most efficient solution.

```
const object = [{...}]; // put the object you provided in the array

console.log(count(object)); // returns 3

function count(root) {
    return root.children.length? 1 + Math.max(...root.children.map(item => count(item))) : 1;
}
```

Or, If that hurts your eyes...:

```
function count(root) {
    if(root.children.length) {
        return 1 + Math.max(...root.children.map(item => count(item)));
    } else return 1;
}
```

I'm curious how you have done the recursive function. I'm waiting for comments.